# Gradle - Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am receiving the following error when gradle checks maven for dependencies:

```
Error transferring file: Permission denied: connect
```

I have found that the issue may be related to a [known bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696) in JDK 1.7 related to IPv6.  The workaround, is to set `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in the Java VM options.

I have done this, and still receive the same error.  I have tried setting every possible environment parameter I can think of, including MAVEN_OPTS, GRADLE_OPTS, _JPI_VM_OPTIONS, JAVA_OPTS, etc.  Nothing appears to work.  Could I be overlooking something simple here?

Comment: Are you able to connect to http://repo1.maven.org from a browser?   It could just be that you are behind a network device that is blocking access?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` when using gradle from the command line (with Minecraft Forge). When it fetches the dependencies and other files, it would throw a `permission denied: connect` error.

My solution to this problem is to look for a configuration file (.ini) and add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`, or I use it as an argument in the CLI, in this case:

`gradlew cleancache --refresh-dependencies -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true setupDecompWorkspace eclipse`.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds more like missing credentials against the given repository. In Maven you have to set those informations in the settings.xml file.

You need to authenticate against the given repository.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'user'
            password 'password'
        }
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not the issue... All of those settings are controlled by our build process.  Further lending to my belief that this is an IPv6/VPN issue, is that I have no issues running the same build on a computer that is physically on the network.  Attempting to build over VPN though fails with "Permission denied: connect".  Same code.

Answer (score 0):

in Windows open -> Network and Sharing Center by searching it in windows start -> search

It will list the LAN connection and VPN

Go to the VPN

click on the connection.

click on properties button 
un select ipv6 to disable